# How to get local tap position in onTapGesture?

Tags: swiftui

Have some rendered image and need to determine tap position relative to image. Seems to be simple, but can't find the answer

```
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image(uiImage: drawRectangle()) // some rendered image
        .onTapGesture {
          // print(x, y)?
        }
```

Answer (score 12):

Found this solution:

```
        .gesture(
            DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .global)
                .onChanged { value in
                  self.position = value.location
                }
                .onEnded { _ in
                  self.position = .zero
                }
        )
```

setting `minimumDistance: 0` will call onChanged immediately

Answer (score 8):

I did try using `DragGesture` with `minimumDistance: 0` but it hijacks my table view's scroll gesture.

So I preferred to use a proper `UITapGestureRecognizer` added to a plain transparent `UIView` embed in a`TappableView` SwitUI `UIViewRepresentable` instead.

```
struct TappableView: UIViewRepresentable
{
    var tapCallback: (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void

    typealias UIViewType = UIView

    func makeCoordinator() -> TappableView.Coordinator
    {
        Coordinator(tapCallback: self.tapCallback)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TappableView>) -> UIView
    {
        let view = UIView()
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.handleTap(sender:))))
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<TappableView>)
    {
    }

    class Coordinator
    {
        var tapCallback: (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void

        init(tapCallback: @escaping (UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void)
        {
            self.tapCallback = tapCallback
        }

        @objc func handleTap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
        {
            self.tapCallback(sender)
        }
    }
}
```

Then just add it as a `.overlay` to the SwiftUI view you want taps added to.

```
.overlay(
    TappableView { gesture in
        // Just use the regular UIKit gesture as you want!
})
```

Comment: Looks like a good solution. For someone not experienced with UIKit gesture code, could you please give an example by filling out the "<// Just use the regular UIKit gesture as you want!>"?  Perhaps something that would give the result of what the OP is seeking?

Comment: You will most likely use `gesture.view`'s `frame` or `bounds` to find out the tap location

Answer (score 0):

```
.onTapGesture { location in
    print("Tapped at \(location)")
}
```

This onTapGesture() variant is available from iOS 16 and later.
If you want the global location – i.e., where your tap took place relative to the top-left corner of the entire screen – you should add the coordinateSpace parameter like this:

```
.onTapGesture(coordinateSpace: .global) { location in
    print("Tapped at \(location)")
}
```